# Почему метод возвращает [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть метод `checkWinner` который который срабатывает при клике на компонент `<ButtonResult checkWinner={this.checkWinner}/>`. Данный метод находить находить наибольшее значение ключа в объекте `this.state` и выводит в консоль.
Проблема заключается в том что выводит `{"[object Object]":1}`, а вместо `[object Object]` должен быть `id` к примеру `voute1`

**Main.js:**

```js
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            vote1: 0,
            vote2: 0,
            vote3: 0,
            vote4: 0,
            vote5: 0,
        }
        this.increaseVote = this.increaseVote.bind(this);
        this.checkWinner = this.checkWinner.bind(this);
    }
    increaseVote(id) {
        return this.setState(state => {
            console.log({[id]: state[id]});
            return {
                [id]: state[id] + 1
            }
        })
    }
    checkWinner(id) {
        console.log(typeof id)
        console.log(id)
        console.log(typeof{[id]: Math.max(...Object.values(this.state))})
        console.log({[id]: Math.max(...Object.values(this.state))})
        return this.setState(state => {
            return JSON.stringify({
                [id.toString()]: Math.max(...Object.values(state))
            })
        })
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
          <List>
            <Item text="&#128540;" id="vote1" increaseVote={this.increaseVote} state={this.state}/>
            <Item text="&#128520;" id="vote2" increaseVote={this.increaseVote} state={this.state}/>
            <Item text="&#128640;" id="vote3" increaseVote={this.increaseVote} state={this.state}/>
            <Item text="&#128526;" id="vote4" increaseVote={this.increaseVote} state={this.state}/>
            <Item text="&#128566;" id="vote5" increaseVote={this.increaseVote} state={this.state}/>
          </List>
          <ButtonResult checkWinner={this.checkWinner}/>
          <Winner/>
        </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

**Winner.js:**

```js
export default class Winner extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="block-winner"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Item.js:**

```js
export default class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { id, text, state, increaseVote } = this.props;
        const onClick = () => increaseVote(id);
        return (
            <li>
                <Button onClick={onClick} id={id} text={text}/>
                <Count text={state[id]}/>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

**ButtonResult.js: **

```js
export default class ButtonResult extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { checkWinner } = this.props;
        return (
            <button onClick={checkWinner} className="button-result">Result</button>
        )
    }
}
```

**Button.js:**

```js
export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
            const { id, text, onClick } = this.props;
        return (
            <button onClick={onClick} className="button" id={id}>{text}</button>
        )
    }
}
```

**Count.js:**

```js
export default class Count extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { text } = this.props;
        return (
            <p className="count-click">{text}</p>
        )
    }
}
```

**List.js:**

```js
export default class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-buttons" id="listButtons">{this.props.children}</ul>
        )
    }
}
```

**Wrapper.js:**

```js
export default class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">{this.props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Выведи в консоль сам `id`... Проверь его `typeof id`...

Comment: @ksa вывело объект

Comment: Что собственно ожидаемо...

Comment: @ksa я пробовал применить JSON.stringify но результат не дало, может я не в том направление иду.
checkWinner(id) {
        return this.setState(state => {
            return JSON.stringify({
                [id]: Math.max(...Object.values(state))
            })
        })
    }

Comment: Дело в том что я ведь не знаю с какими ИД ты имеешь дело. Как вариант, сам `id` преобразовать - `id.toString()` или `JSON.stringify(id)`... Т.е. нужно понять какой объект у тебя записан в `id`.

Comment: Нужно понять, как вызывается `increaseVote` в `Item`. Если компонент из внешнего пакета, то смотреть документацию. На мой субъективный взгляд, чтобы заработал этот пример, можно сделать так `increaseVote={() => this.increaseVote('vote1')}`. Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы появился минимально рабочий пример.

Comment: @ДенисЛагуткин  добавил все компоненты приложения

Comment: @ksa я добавил все компоненты приложения

Comment: а какой вообще `id` ты ожидал увидеть???

Comment: В `Item`, после `const { id, text, state, increaseVote } = this.props;`, посмотри чему равен `id`. В `const onClick = () => increaseVote(id)` пойдет именно он.

Comment: @NANO_996 кстати вот и я :) спасибо за хороший старт, помните, я вам давал мой первый ответ? ;)

Comment: не по теме вопроса конечно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта решения проблемы. Все зависит от задачи.

1. в `Main.js` модифицировать методы `increaseVote` и `checkWinner`, которые в качестве аргумента будут принимать [`SyntheticEvent`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/events.html) (этот аргумент возникает в `button.onclick` в компоненте `Button`), в нем есть поле `target`, оно ссылается на элемент в котором произошло событие `click`, и  указывает на `button` в `DOM` дереве. С него нужно взять `id`.
   Код для `increaseVote` будет выглядеть так:

```
 increaseVote(event) {
      const id = event.target.id;
      return this.setState(state => {
        console.log({
          [id]: state[id]
        });
        return {
          [id]: state[id] + 1
        }
      })
    }
```

2. Или изменить вызов функции `onClick` компоненте `Button` передав в качестве аргумента `id`. Код для `Button` будет выглядеть так:

```
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {id, text, onClick} = this.props;
    return (
      <button onClick={() => onClick(id)} className="button" id={id}>{text}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

обработчик `onlick` первым параметром принимает объект события.

Соответственно здесь

```
<button onClick={checkWinner}
```

в метод `checkWinner` передается не `id`, а объект события о нажатии кнопки.